# Xamarin button shadow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin forms and I'm trying to add a shadow on a button. I tried to create a Custom effect for making shadow but instead of creating this effect on the button, it has been added to the text inside the button. Is there any way to add a shadow on a button?
I need to make this for android.

Comment: You need to use Elevation property for Android.

Comment: for android https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/button-padding-shadow

Comment: Elevation works fine